# Slide Number in the sidebar of PaloAlto theme in beamer

Tags: beamer, page-numbering

I would like to insert   number_of_the_current_slide/total_number_of_slides   at the bottom of the sidebar of the PaloAlto theme in the beamer class, without any changes in the other features. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

I have found how to do it. This was my first typeset:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\title{Lie Algebras}
\author{Emanuele}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Piano della presentazione}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and the following is the second:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\addtobeamertemplate{footline}
{%
   \usebeamercolor[fg]{author in sidebar}
   \vskip-1cm\hskip10pt
   %\insertpagenumber\,/\,\insertpresentationendpage\kern1em\vskip2pt%
   \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber\kern1em\vskip2pt%
}
\title{Lie Algebras}
\author{Emanuele}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Piano della presentazione}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The difference is that in the second typeset there is the numbering of the pages in the bottom of the sidebar.

Comment: Will this affect how the table of contents are written in the sidebar for navigation?